# I import code and have a button sending you to another activity. What is going wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

What is wrong with this piece of code? It is supposed to import text, and make a button send you to another activity. The piece where I import text works just fine.

Thanks for the help!

```
public class Butik_resultat extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_butik_resultat);

    //Modtager din søgning, som du gjorde i Butik.class
    TextView modtag_butik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.modtag_butik);
    modtag_butik.setText("Du søgte efter denne butik: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("SEND_BUTIK"));


    addButtonlistener();
} 



void addButtonlistener() {
    // lytter til knap
    Button send_til_kort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kort);
    send_til_kort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent send_til_kort = new Intent(v.getContext(), Butik_kort.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(send_til_kort);
        }
    });

}
```

here is the LogCat output:

```
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Butik_resultat}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at com.example.test.Butik_resultat.addButtonlistener(Butik_resultat.java:31)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at com.example.test.Butik_resultat.onCreate(Butik_resultat.java:24)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
06-13 14:51:25.629: E/AndroidRuntime(20585):    ... 11 more
06-13 14:51:27.939: I/Process(20585): Sending signal. PID: 20585 SIG: 9
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Butik_resultat" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/modtag_butik"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/modtag_butik"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/ingen_resultat"
    android:text="@string/ingen_resultat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/kort"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kort"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:hint="@string/kvickly_ry"
    android:text="@string/kvickly_ry"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kort"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:hint="@string/kort"
    android:text="@string/kort"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/kort"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:text="Nærmeste Butik"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Comment: If it crashes post the stacktrace ?

Comment: Have you modified you AndroidManifest.xml ? if not, take a look at [this site](http://sogacity.com/add-new-activity-to-android-manifest-file/)

Comment: do you ever call `addButtonlistener` ? because its commented

Comment: _getIntent().getExtras().getString(...)_ : The Intent might be null if no Intent started the Activity, for example with the launching activity, or the Bundle extras might also be null. In both cases a NullPointerException might be thrown.

Comment: @x4rf41 what should i write instead? i'm new to java.

Comment: @Asger Noer: check all the other comments and sunil's answer, they are all good suggestions

Comment: @x4rf41 I have tried sunil's answer but it don't seem to work... it just crashes. It is the `addButtonListener` that is causing it to crash. I just don't know how to fix it...

Comment: thats why i said look at all the comments, like the one from Triode: `If it crashes post the stacktrace`

Comment: Can you post your xml

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
public class Butik_resultat extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_butik_resultat);

        //Modtager din søgning, som du gjorde i Butik.class
        TextView modtag_butik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.modtag_butik);
        modtag_butik.setText("Du søgte efter denne butik: ");

    Button send_til_kort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kort);
        send_til_kort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent send_til_kort = new Intent(Butik_resultat.this, Butik_kort.class);
                startActivity(send_til_kort);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html); that means you have some problem in your XML. Check it...